# OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found when using nunit and autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nunit, autofac

I'm trying to get nunit and autofac working together for a Selenium test framework.

I understand why I'm getting the `OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found` error (because nunit cannot start `UnitTest1` if it has a ctor which isn't empty), but I can't figure out how I can work around this.

It seems like a chicken and egg problem; nunit requires `IHomePage` for the test to run, but the container isn't created because `SetUp` or `OneTimeSetUp` aren't called until the test has started running.

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        IHomePage _homePage;
        private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<HomePage>().As<IHomePage>();
            builder.RegisterType<LoginPage>().As<ILoginPage>();
            Container = builder.Build();
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var writer = scope.Resolve<ITestRunner>();
                writer.RunTest();
            }
        }

        public UnitTest1(IHomePage homePage)
        {
            _homePage = homePage;
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestMethod11()
        {
            // do something testing with _homePage
            _homePage.ClickLogin();
        }
    }

    public class HomePage : IHomePage
    {
        ILoginPage _loginPage;

        public HomePage(ILoginPage loginPage)
        {
            _loginPage = loginPage;
        }

        public ILoginPage ClickLogin()
        {
            return _loginPage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `UnitTest1` shouldn't have an explicit constructor. The test runner creates the class for you and so it calls the implicit parameterless constructor. You have created a constructor with a parameter - this removed the implicit constructor and that is what OneTimeSetup is complaining about.

Comment: @iakobski thanks - but doesn't that mean the autofac container won't be available to the tests (```object not set to an instance of an object``` for ```_homePage```?

Comment: What is calling `public UnitTest1(IHomePage homePage)`? Surely the object being tested should be created within the test class? What am I missing?

Comment: I would normally expect to see `_homePage` set in the setup method or in the test itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will only be a partial answer, 'cause I know nothing about Autofac.

BUT from the NUnit point of view...

NUnit constructs your classes. To do that it needs either

- A default constructor, OR
- A non-default constructor for which you have supplied arguments.

You have a non-default constructor, but you are not telling NUnit what args to use with that constructor.

The way you tell NUnit what args to use is to supply them as arguments to the 
`TestFixtureAttribute` or by using a `TestFixtureSourceAttribute`, which adds a level of indirection. Perhaps somebody else can add how Autofac interacts with NUnit in this situation.